# R: Paste function arguments with list

Tags: r, list, function

How can I paste arguments to a function using a list.

For example, I want to paste the arguments of `l` to the function `f`:

```
f <- function(a, b, c){
  return(a + b + c)
}

l <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)

# here is the error:
f(unlist(l)) # the expected value is 6
```

Is there a simple/elegant/possible solution for this?

## Edit

I have a function `f` that returns a list which should be parsed into another function `f.other` (which also takes other inputs), and I try to shorten the code. For example

```
f <- function() list(b = 2, c = 3)
f.other <- function(a, b, c) a + b + c

l <- f()

# what I try to achieve is this (with shorter code)
f.other(a = 1, b = l$b, c = l$c)

# something like this
f.other(a = 1, do.call(l))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a function for that:

```
do.call(f, l)
[1] 6
```

The function `?do.call` facilitates evaluating function arguments programmatically.

**edit**

To your second question, if you would like to add arguments after the list is created, concatenate the new arguments to the list:

```
l <- list(b=2, c=3)
```

As it is written, it is incomplete and will throw an error if we tried `do.call(f, l)`. To add the extra argument, we can use:

```
l2 <- c(a=1, l)
```

In this case we added `a=1` to the existing list to run `do.call(f, l2)`.

Comment: That seems to be the fast answer! One small additional question: say I have not `a = 1` in the list but want to specify it in the `do.call`-function. Can I do something like this?

Comment: Thanks... The issue is the following, I have a function that returns a list and the content of the list should be parsed into another function. Due to the complexity of each function I would prefer a simple call to parse the arguments of the list to the function, however, there might be additional arguments.

Comment: Add them to the list. I will add more due to the new information you are adding.